# Handling multi-line HTML inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using Javascript to define a button behaviour on a web page. The behaviour I am after is to insert some new HTML somewhere on my page, but I would like to use the MVC extension method `Html.EditorFor` to define the new HTML which will be inserted.

What I would like to do is the following:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("@(Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeModelProperty))").insertBefore(<somewhere>);
});
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the `MvcHtmlString` returned by the call to `EditorFor` renders as multi-line HTML, resulting in invalid Javascript:

```
$("<div>
<label for="ModelData_SomeModelProperty">SomeModelProperty</label>
</div>
<div> ....
```

In an ideal world, I could get `EditorFor` to somehow render all of the above on a single line, or use some kind of special Javascript syntax to define a multi-line string (like using single quotes in C#), but so far I'm drawing a blank.

I've tried calling `ToHtmlString` and hand-editing the resulting string to remove line-breaks, and I'm aware that I can escape the new lines in Javascript using a `/`, but the problem with doing so is that I then have to handle the escaped HTML, which looks a little like the following:

```
$("&lt;div&gt;
&lt;label        for=&quot;ModelData_SomeModelProperty&quot;&gt;SomeModelProperty&lt;/label&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt; .... (you get the idea)
```

I was just wondering whether anyone had tried anything similar and might have a more elegant approach?

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. You can always generate it in a hidden `<div>` and then in then handle the button click to display and/or clone it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to get it written into a hidden div in html instead of directly into the javascript. Then you can just read it from the dom to use in you script.

So you page would have a

```
<div style="display:none" id="hiddenArea">

...insert whatever you want in here 
with newline or whatever...

</div>
```

And then in your javascript:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    var source = $("#hiddenArea").html();
    $(source).insertBefore(<somewhere>);
});
```

Comment: Yeah I was trying to dream up something along these lines after seeing the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115360/multi-line-string-insert-using-jquery). Unfortunately i need the result of the call to `Html.EditorFor` at the time when the button is pressed, not when the page is rendered, so I don't think I can do this...

Comment: Update re: the above - I found a way of parsing out and replacing the runtime variables that I needed from the resulting HTML, making this a much more effective approach. Thanks!

Comment: Great! If your parsing problem is getting messy you might want to look at something like http://handlebarsjs.com/ for js templating

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe create a HTML helper so you much more control on what's returned and how it is formatted.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application

Comment: Thanks yeah, combination of this and the above proved to be my solution. Hadn't really had much of a delve into custom html helpers before now so it's been a good experience!