# Unable to create nested elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm tying to write a function to return list element with few things in it i.e.

```
function generateSurpriseMe(month) {
    var surprise = $('

        <li class="queue-month">
            <h3>'+ month +'</h3>
            ...
        </li>

    ');

    return surprise;

}
```

where month is a parameter that needs to be inserted inside (its not the only one, but to keep this simple I'll only include it). But I'm receiving "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error in console and can't figure out what it is, error referees to second line of code `var surprise = $('`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiline strings should end with `\`

```
var surprise = $('\
\
    <li class="queue-month">\
        <h3>'+ month +'</h3>\
        ...\
    </li>\
 \
');
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115360/multi-line-string-insert-using-jquery) for more details

Answer (score 2):

The `string` should be completed on the same line in javascript.

Change:

```
var surprise = $('

    <li class="queue-month">
        <h3>'+ month +'</h3>
        ...
    </li>

');
```

TO:

```
var surprise = $('<li class="queue-month"><h3>'+ month +'</h3>...</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

your question was a little vague, not sure if this is what you're trying to accomplish

```
var today = new Date();
$('#myTarget').after('<li class="queue-month"><h3>' + today + '</h3></li>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cb3fk3dL/

Answer (score 0):

If you type the codes in a good Javascript IDE, it will prompt you with a more accurate advice.

For example, I am using WebStorm. After paste your codes in WebStorm, it prompts with a red wave line at the end of each unterminated string line. When I hover a red wave line, it prompts with an explanation of the error "Unclosed string literal" like in the attached screenshot. I love webStorm.

[image]