# <i class="fa fa-trash"> is not working in <span></span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was going through the solutions of Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, and tried every other way to sort it out but I am still getting this error with this code

```
$("input").on("keypress",function(event){

if(event.which === 13)
{
    var ToDotext=($(this).val());   

$("ul").append("<li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></span> "  +  ToDotext  + "</li>");
$(this).val("");
}
```

}
);

whenever I put `<i class="fa fa-trash"` in `<span></span>` I am getting this error, without `<i class="fa fa-trash">` things are working fine.

Comment: Invalid string quotation / syntax error in `append("...")`

Comment: use class='fa fa-trash' insetead of class="fa fa-trash"

Comment: Adding to the above comments you are missing </i>

Comment: Thanks, @marekful It was written with double quotes on font awesome website. But with single quotes, it's working great. thanks again:)

Answer (score 2):

Change the appending line to this.

```
$("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> "  +  ToDotext  + "</li>");
```

Changes:

1. `fa fa-trash` is in single quotes as you are using double quotes outside.
2. close the `i` tag

Suggestions:

1. Instead of using `<i>` inside `<span>`, apply the class on span or remove span altogether and keep i tag.
2. Use jQuery element creation methods. like this.

   `$('ul li ').html($('<i>', {class: 'fa fa-trash'}));`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
   $("input").on("keypress",function(event){
    if(event.which === 13)
       {
           var ToDotext=($(this).val());   

        $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span>"+ ToDotext  + "</li>");

         $(this).val("");
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the error in your script.

```
$("ul").append("<li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></span>"+ToDotext+"</li>");
```

If you add component, with this code, the actual components are added as follows.

```
<li><span><i class=fa fa-trash></span>ToDoText</li>
```

As you see above, the class names of the `<i>` tag must be quoted with " or ' but it is not like that.
It is because you used the same quotes adding the components.
If you change "fa fa-trash" -> 'fa fa-trash', the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have double quotations inside double quotations, simple example:

open your console:

```
var newElem = "<h1 class="rock">Hello There !!</h1>";
newElem // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

You will have to enclose you `class` and other `html attributes` inside a single quotations, like so:

```
var newElem = "<h1 class='rock'>Hello There !!</h1>";
```

The below line:

```
$("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></span> "  +  ToDotext  + "</li>");
```

Would have to change to:

```
$("ul").append("<li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></span> "  +  ToDotext  + "</li>");
```

Additional ::- if you writing long concatenations you probably want to **[SPLIT IT UP INTO ADDITIONAL LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3115375/4381665)**